# Prove that 2 is not equal to 1

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that $2 \neq 1$ in an ordered field $P$ using the ordered field axioms. We know that $0\neq 1$ by axiom, and $2 =1+1$ by definition. We also know that $1 \in P$ and $1+1=2 \in P$ by the identity axiom and closure of $P$ under addition, respectively. I just need like the first step on how to start.

Comment: Assume 2=1 and subtract something.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: This should really be an answer. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose for contradiction $2=1$.

By definition, this is equivalent to $1+1 = 1$. Then $1+\color{red}{1+(-1)}=\color{red}{1+(-1)}$, which lets us conclude $1+0 = 0$, implying $1=0$, an obvious contradiction.

If you're feeling fancier, you could instead say $1+1=1$ leads to an immediate contradiction because $n+n=n$ is only true if $n$ is the additive identity, which $1$ is not (by definition).